# Request timeout 502 error while uploading large files in React JS/Dot net core Single Page application

Tags: c#, reactjs, .net-core, axios, single-page-application

I have a single page application build in react js as front end and dot net core as server.

I am trying to upload the file in the server. It works fine in local but for files larger than 30 mb, files doesnt even reach the server and error out with 502 bad gateway.

I have used both buffer(IFormFile) and multipart stream upload but same result following below artical.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-3.1#upload-large-files-with-streaming

I have added web config for maxAllowedContentLength and requestTimeout as well.

My service call is below.

const data = new FormData();
    Array.from(file).forEach(file => data.append('file', file));

```
return axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: url,
    data: data,
    config: { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' } }
})
```

Please suggest what else to look for.

Comment: 502 error code means that the request is received by the HTTP server but then doesn't go any further. It does not have anything to do with React. I think you should show us your http server/reverse proxy configuration.

Comment: <aspNetCore requestTimeout="01:00:00" processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout">
        <environmentVariables />
      </aspNetCore>
      <security>
        <requestFiltering>
          <!-- 1 GB -->
          <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
        </requestFiltering>
      </security>